# How to open file based on user input?

Tags: c++, filenames, istream

This code keeps giving me errors i dont know what Im doing wrong? 
How can I request the user to input the filename and then open that file and perform
tasks with the data.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{ 
ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;
string fileName;

cout << "Enter the data file Name : " << endl;//asks user to input filename
cin >> fileName; //inputs user input into fileName

inData.open(fileName); //heres where i try to open the file with the users input?
outData.open(fileName);
cout << fileName;
return 0;   
}
```

The code keeps giving me errors. I have tried to use getline? I want the fileName to be string 
and not char.

Comment: Usually when you say you get errors, it's a good idea to include those errors. You know... just in case our crystal balls aren't in the shop getting repaired.

Comment: Sorry, but i fiqured this was a simple problem?

Comment: It might be (and in this case *is*) but including the error you are getting is always a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that next time:)

Comment: @user1725435 You can edit the question to include all the necessary information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `std::string` objects to the parameters, not actual null-terminated char pointers. To do that, use `c_str`:

```
inData.open(fileName.c_str());
outData.open(fileName.c_str());
```

Comment: What does c_str() mean?

Comment: @user1725435 [Here's the documentation for std::string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: Note: This has been changed for C++11.